LABjs: how to extract data from a previous loop?
I'm working on an experiment in LABjs and I've run into a problem with accessing data that was input as part of a task loop earlier in the experiment.
Basically, I am trying to run a simulation of a randomly selected trial (for the purposes of determining bonus payment), wherein a random problem from the set is chosen, and I extract the participant's actual response from that trial to determine which of two lotteries to run (option A, or option B, depending on which they picked).
The information was saved as a variable named finalChoice using this code structure:
----[run]----
a.onclick = () => {
  this.state.finalChoice = 'A';
}

b.onclick = () => {
  this.state.finalChoice = 'B';
}

----[end]----

this.data.finalChoice = this.state.finalChoice;

I can console log this and get accurate data, and finalChoice is saved as a variable in the final dataset output with one value for each iteration of the loop, so I know this part at least is working as intended.
The issue arises when trying to access this data later in the experiment. I have tried a couple of different things, including using this.data.finalChoice directly as a variable, but I have a feeling I'm on the wrong track. I just don't really know enough about either javascript or the internal structure of LABjs to figure it out myself, so any advice/help would be appreciated!

you mention a loop - you've shown no loop - please add detail to your question and code that presumably includes a loop
